# Setting up an Ldap authentication system with my web application

Tags: php, jquery, ldap

I am an admin user that has full access to a web server within my company. I built a web application that authenticates to its local database (mysql). Ive been thinking of the possibility of setting up an ldap authentication system. I dont have access to the ldap server itself but have some contacts to reach them if needed. Just wondering how complex is it to setup? Do i require access to the ldap server or would just having its ip and server info suffice in terms of scripting? Im really just want to know how much work would be needed to do this since ive mever done this.

Comment: Is it Active Directory, OpenLDAP, or something else entirely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually just did this, theres a `php-ldap` extension, to check login credentials is basically as simple as:

```
private $ldap_url = "";
private $ldap_base_dn = "ou=Something, dc=SomethingElse, dc=local";

function login($username, $password) {
    $ds = ldap_connect($this->ldap_url);
    if (!$ds) {
        return false;
    }
    try {
        $r = ldap_bind($ds, $username, $password);
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!$r) {
        return false;
    }
    $sr = ldap_search($ds, $this->ldap_base_dn, "samaccountname=".$username);
    $user_data = ldap_get_entries($ds, $sr);
    return $user_data;
}
```

As long as you know the ldap url and the base dn settings, I think it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the details, would anyone know of any easy way to find the ldap url and base DN? I got access to the app server but not sure how to find it.